# Gradle sync failed (.rawproto), failed to save settings

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I've installed Android studio and created my first application from standard pattern. Now I have problems with opening it: 
[image]

I opened idea.log and started to search by word 'fail'. Found:

```
    2017-06-14 19:56:31,148 [ 190717]   WARN - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - Save settings failed 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\HelloWorld\.idea\workspace.xml___jb_tmp___ (ϲ롧ᮮ ⡤ﲲ
    at com.intellij.util.lang.CompoundRuntimeException.throwIfNotEmpty(CompoundRuntimeException.java:151)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.save(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:166)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.StoreUtil.save(StoreUtil.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectImpl.save(ProjectImpl.java:343)
    at com.intellij.ide.SaveAndSyncHandlerImpl.doSaveDocumentsAndProjectsAndApp(SaveAndSyncHandlerImpl.java:137)
    at com.intellij.ide.SaveAndSyncHandlerImpl.saveProjectsAndDocuments(SaveAndSyncHandlerImpl.java:125)
    at com.intellij.ide.SaveAndSyncHandlerImpl$2.lambda$onFrameDeactivated$0(SaveAndSyncHandlerImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$300(TransactionGuardImpl.java:40)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:113)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:109)
    at com.intellij.ide.SaveAndSyncHandlerImpl$2.onFrameDeactivated(SaveAndSyncHandlerImpl.java:92)
    at com.intellij.ide.FrameStateManagerImpl.fireDeactivationEvent(FrameStateManagerImpl.java:84)
    at com.intellij.ide.FrameStateManagerImpl.access$500(FrameStateManagerImpl.java:32)
    at com.intellij.ide.FrameStateManagerImpl$2.lambda$applicationDeactivated$0(FrameStateManagerImpl.java:70)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:222)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:378)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$6.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:291)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:326)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:310)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:631)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\HelloWorld\.idea\workspace.xml___jb_tmp___
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was decided by upgrade